# How to select/deselect a DataGrid row according with state of Checkbox inside this row?

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox, datagrid

I've developing a WPF application which has one window with DataGrid. This DataGrid has binding to collection of "Person" objects. "Person" object has a property called "IsObjSelected". Every Row in DataGrid has a Checkbox in the first column. And state of this Checkbox and selection of Row should display a value of this property. So I need a next behavior:

1. When I click on Row in every place - it should check the Checkbox and make IsObjSelected = true.
2. When I check an unchecked Checkbox and it will be checked - it should select the row where this Checkbox is placed and make IsObjSelected = true.
3. When I check again a checked Checkbox and it will be unchecked - it should deselect the row where this Checkbox is placed and make IsObjSelected = false.

For my initial test a create a test application. And there I create a binding for a IsChecked property of Checkbox and IsSelected property of Row to this property IsObjSelected.And it works correctly for the 1st and 3rd items of my TODO list. But in case for the 2nd item it give a strange behavior. When I check and unchecked Checkbox - it check and immediately uncheck it again + select an immediately deselect the Row. And I don't know why.

Here is how it looks:

[image]

Here is my code. Class "Person":

```
public class Person: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;

    public bool IsObjSelected
    {
        get => _isObjSelected;
        set
        {
            _isObjSelected = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(IsObjSelected));
        }
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get => _name;
        set
        {
            _name = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(Name));
        }
    }

    public DateTime DateTime
    {
        get => _dateTime;
        set
        {
            _dateTime = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(DateTime));
        }
    }

    public Person(bool isSelected, string name, DateTime dateTime)
    {
        _isObjSelected = isSelected;
        _name = name;
        _dateTime = dateTime;
    }

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private bool _isObjSelected;
    private string _name;
    private DateTime _dateTime;
}
```

Here is a part of my window with DataGrid:

```
</DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsObjSelected, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Selected"
                                SortDirection="Ascending"
                                Width="auto">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <CheckBox HorizontalAlignment="Center" IsChecked="{Binding IsObjSelected, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name"
                            Binding="{Binding Name}"
                            SortDirection="Ascending"
                            Width="*"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Date and Time"
                            Binding="{Binding DateTime}"
                            SortDirection="Ascending"
                            Width="auto"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

So, in my logic, checking of Checkbox should change a value of property IsObjSelected. And this also should trigger a changing of Row selection, and vice versa. But it doesn't work correctly.

Why it happens and how to fix that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Triggers to achieve this behavior.

You don't need this

```
<Setter Property="IsSelected"
        Value="{Binding IsObjSelected, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

Replace it with this

```
<Style.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsObjSelected}" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="True" />
    </DataTrigger>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsObjSelected}" Value="False">
        <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="False" />
    </DataTrigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Muhammad. I've tried it and it seems it works. But after this changes it works only for case when I check/uncheck Checkbox - it selects/deselects a Row. But when I a select a Row - it doesn't check the Checkbox as it was before. I tried also to add a DataTrigger for the Checkbox where create a binding - Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridRow, Mode=FindAncestor}}". But it doesn't work. It doesn't check a Checkbox when I click on Row. Mb it because I also has a binding between IsChecked property and IsObjSelected

Comment: I think this could be done simpler from code behind.. Using `SelectionChanged` event on DataGrid, you can get the selected person from event arguments, then set `IsObjSelected` to true.